# How to Prevent Double Submission in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I would like to prevent double submission in Django. The problem arises when the user clicks on the back button in the browser. I know that I can use JavaScript, but I would like to fix the issue using Python.

Here is the code:

```
#views.py
class HandleChannelFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'details.html'
    template_added = "success.html"
    form_class = MediaForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('data')
 
    def form_valid(self, form):
        data = self.request.session.get('data', None)
 
        if not data:
            messages.error(self.request, 'No channel data found in session.')
        else:
            category_id = form.cleaned_data['category'].id if form.cleaned_data['category'] else None
            language_id = form.cleaned_data['language'].id if form.cleaned_data['language'] else None
 
            data.update({
                'body': form.cleaned_data['body'],
                'category_id': category_id,
                'category_name': form.cleaned_data['category'].name if form.cleaned_data['category'] else None,
                'language_id': language_id,
                'nsfw': form.cleaned_data['nsfw'],  # Add the nsfw value to the data dictionary
            })
            counter = self.request.session.get('counter', {})
            StoreChannelData.save_data(data, counter)
 
        return render(self.request, self.template_added, {'data': data, 'media_form': form})
```

I also attempted to resolve the issue by using redirect and HttpResponseRedirect, but it did not resolve the problem. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!